# why does every reboot require source ~/.zshrc for plugins to work?

Tags: zsh

I installed Oh_My_Zsh, and Zsh works fine.

However, after reboot, zsh seems unable to find plugins.

It shows "zsh: command not found: z" for example

Everytime, I have to manually source ~/.zshrc to make things work

What should I do ?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: To those voting to close this question please read the second part of this statement carefully - Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. - I am happy to consider a shell as a tool that is **primarily for programming**.

Comment: Z shell itself advertises itself as being primarily for interactive use; shell scripting is a secondary concern. This question has virtually nothing to do with the scripting aspect of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

I put plugin list at the end of the file, and this upsets ZSH somehow.

You need to put plugin list straight after

## Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.

this line to make things work.